# ServiceNow personal developer instance enabled SecurityOperations plugin?

Tags: servicenow

I've deployed a ServiceNow developer instance running version 'London' and can't see an option to enable SecurityOperations plugin. However I had a previous instance and I'm sure it was a straight forward operation from the instance manager.

Does anyone know how to do this or whats changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Security Operations modules can now be directly activated from the plugin list of your instance. You can navigate to System Definitions -> Plugins and then search for Security to get your required plugin.

[image]